# WCF proxy convert List<string[]> to List<List<string>>

Tags: wcf, svcutil.exe, wcf-proxy

In my WCF web method i have a operation contract which accepts List of string array, but when i create a proxy for this service it converts that to List of List of string.

```
    List<string[]> to List<List<string>>.
```

Can anyone please tell me if there is some way i can make sure that this does not happen and my proxy also contains List

Thanks

Comment: When you add a service reference, you can chose whether to use Generics or Arrays for collections, look to see if you have set it to `Generic Collections`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the Service Reference in VS, go to Configure Service Reference and set the collection type to System.Collections.Generic.List. That should fix it. If you are using svcutil the switch is /collectionType: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347733.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried editing the code generated by svcutil.exe? Editing generated code = ugh, I know, but ...

Comment: Ya right now i am doing that so that i can at least continue to code on my client side, but because i am working in a team and our services are changing every day, its a headache. I was thinking if there is some flag in svcutil which can help but couldn't find one

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the advanced settings, and you can change the collection type there:

[image]

I got this image from https://i.stack.imgur.com/bkwoc.png